# foreach loop cant find values of json object and display on php page

Tags: php, json, foreach

I got some data in my data/clients.json file and I'm trying to reach for some of the keys and values and display them in my php file. It does not work and i can not figure out why.

My clients.json file looks like:

```
{
    "data": {
        "nikajakubec": {
            "name": "nika",
            "loans": {
                "amount": "1000",
                "reason": "for garden"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my PHP file:

```
 <?php
  $sData = file_get_contents('data/clients.json');
  $jData = json_decode($sData);
  $jClient = $jData->data->$sUsername;
  foreach ($jClient->loans as $jLoans) {
      echo  " 
            <div>
              <div>Amount:$jLoans->loans-></div>
              <div>Reason:$sUserName->reason</div>
              </div>";
  } 


  ?>
```

Comment: Can you check that JSON File, That does not look like valid json

Comment: If you add `echo json_last_error()` and or `json_last_error_msg()` you may get help on the error  see http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php

Comment: As of your description, that's probably not the main issue, but I think for "Reason" it should also be `$jLoans->reason ` (instead of `$sUserName`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this:-

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "data": {
        "nikajakubec": {
            "name": "nika",
            "loans": {
                "amount": "1000",
                "reason": "for garden"
            }
        }
    }
}';

$jData = json_decode($json);
  foreach ($jData->data as $user) {
      echo  " 
            <div>
              <div>Amount:". $user->loans->amount ."</div>
              <div>Reason: ". $user->loans->reason ."</div>
              </div>";
  }
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/8HPV5

Comment: Thank you so much it works now!!! Could I have a short question about it to understand how it works or you're busy? THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Alright guys. Everything works now, thanks so much! But I just don't get it.. I mean, why does it work with foreach ($jData->data as $jLoans) if I'm trying to find every $sUserName(nikajakubec in this case) and its $jLoans. Why it doesn't work with something like $jData->data->$sUserName as $jLoans ? Thanks!

Comment: and what does the dot after quotation marks in <div>Reason: ". $jLoans->loans->reason ."</div> mean ? I won't bother you anymore after this :D

Comment: @PetraJakub 1st question -> since it's a multi-dimensional array that's why it won't worked with `$jData->data->$sUserName ` as `$sUserName` has no where there in your json data. 2 question:- `.` used for concatenation of php variable with string.

Answer (score 0):

The field `reason` it's actually nested inside the `loans` prop, not directly in the user.

so instead of 
`$sUserName->reason`
just go
`$jLoans->reason`

And also go `$jLoans->amount` instead of `$jLoans->loans->`

Consider that when you cycle `$jClient->loans` you are going to work on each prop of `loans`, which are 'amount' and 'reason'

Comment: Everything works now, thanks so much! But I just don't get it.. I mean, why does it work with foreach ($jData->data as $jLoans) if I'm trying to find every $sUserName(nikajakubec in this case) and its $jLoans. Why it doesn't work with something like $jData->data->$sUserName as $jLoans ? Thanks!

Comment: The `foreach` takes an argument which could be an array/object or so on, and let you cycle on every element of this "list". Referencing to the item you are currently working on during the loop could be difficult, so it lets you define an alias with `as` to define how you're going to call the current item.
so if you wirte something like `foreach($jData->data->$sUserName as $jLoans)` you will cycle all the props of the `$sUserName` element, which are `amount` and `reason`. You will access them like so: `$jLoans->amount`, `$jLoans->reason`

Comment: N.B. `$jLoans` is just a variable name as another, it's not "strict".
You could also write `foreach($jData->data->$sUserName as $goofy)` and then call `$goofy->amount`. The important is what you are cycling and the props/items of the current item.
Read some more docs about loops if it's still not clear